# How do I select a switch that protects against CAM attack?

Tags: network

Are there any flags/attributes, that I can see when buying an ethernet switch? I mean does it has a little message on the box of the switch, or any tech specs, from where i can see that the given switch is going to survive a CAM attack?

[CAM table attack in 2011?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3600/cam-table-attack-in-2011)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For consumer-grade, off the shelf switches, you are unlikely to find port-security and/or MAC limiting features in unmanaged or 'dumb' switches.

If you move into the managed or 'smart' switch space, you will start to find these features. However they do come at a price, and often require some knowledge of the platform to configure. Typically these switches are used in businesses.

Companies like Cisco, HP and Juniper are companies who produce products which typically include these features. Each product tends to call the feature something different, so you would need to read through the spec sheet and do your research, if unfamiliar with the product or platform.

Comment: The big take away here is that there's nothing magical in the switch itself that protects against CAM floods, it's all about how one configures the device.

Comment: @Scott Pack, very good point there. Hope that was clear enough in my response.